# Windows XP NTP synchronization

Tags: windows-xp, ntp

I am getting the following error message when trying to synchronize a Windows XP to our NTP.
Works with all other Linux servers.

The message I receive is:
**The time sample was rejected because round-trip delay too large.**

The network should be configured correctly. The NTP seems to respond.

Does anyone know what this error message mean?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your clock, select "Adjust time/date" . 
then, go to "internet time" tab and "change settings" button.
Here you can add more time servers.

there is a very complete listing [here](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi#)

also, your problem may be caused by the system not updating as often as desired.
open your regedit.exe and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\w32time\TimeProviders\NtpClient
```

select "SpecialPollInterval" and give it a value lets say 86400. this makes your clock sync every day. (it is set in seconds)

note: make sure your firewall is not blocking [UDP port 123](http://ports.my-addr.com/tcp_port-udp_port-application-and-description.php?port=123) , as NTP needs it not closed in order to sync time correctly.

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo for the answer. The computer is not connected to the internet so we only have the possibility to use the internal NTP. The NTP should be accessible from all networks. The NTP answers on ping, however I don't have the possibility to verify if the port is okay.

Comment: I have not found any solution to this problem. There seems to be no real answer to why this error message occur anywhere. This problem was solved by creating a NTP server on another Windows server.